# SFMC - Triggered Send as Fire Event in Scheduled Automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

All,

We have requirement in which the first step of Automation should be a Triggered Send ( Sending an email based on the Salesforce custom field).

Procedure will be like :

- Triggered Send ( Update Salesforce record from another system and this  should sent an email to customer). This is done and working.
- A journey should start over immediately after this sending a new mail to  contact.
- Sent a follow up mail after 4 Days after a particular step.
- Sent another mail after 1 Days (Just after above step)

Am sure we can achieve the 2,3,4 steps using Automation Studio and 1 using triggered Send.

But is it possible to Fire a Triggered Send to start this Journey?
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a limitation from ExactTarget that they currently do not support the Integration from Salesforce for dropping files into the Enhanced FTP folder.

See their response :

"Hi Ragesh,

You would need to  set up a triggered automation to listen to the specified FTP folder, then when you use the third party app like Filezilla to transfer a file into that folder, the automation starts.

For the Salesforce part, that's not currently possible, it's a limitation of the current integration."

Answer (score 1):

They would likely have to be two separate calls sent at same time. Have one API call hitting the triggered email and then a second consecutive API call activating the Automation (for steps 2, 3 and 4).

Other than that, you would have to change the triggered email to a User-Initiated email and set the automation as a triggered automation and just have the api call drop a CSV file into the FTP for each new event (to trigger the automation).  Depending on volume, this may not be the best approach.

Or finally you can have a timestamp on the trigger email and have it fill into a collect sendable data extension (so there is only a single record per email address) and then run daily automations for day 4 email and day 5 email based on filters of the collect DE.

There may be a more elegant solution through SDK or API, but without building too much custom code, the above are the only solutions I can think of.

Comment: Hi Gortonington, Its seems we need to invoke an API to drop a new file into the enhanced FTP folder. Can you please advise me on how we can achieve this? Is there any helpful doc available? Please share